# In r programming,how to Generate the rtf document with common header and footnote all over the document

Tags: r, rtf, cran

Generating the rtf document with common header and footnote all over the document using R programming. Is there any simple and easy way for it.. Please help me out with this.
i have to customize like in image .
I did not found any clear example or sample code to generate like this.. 
ReportRs is removed from CRAN repository.

[image: Sample document output]

Comment: According to https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/index.html, *"ReporteRs will be maintained but will not evolve anymore. It has been rewritten with no java dependency: The new package is officer."* The author states on https://github.com/davidgohel/officer, *"This package is close to ReporteRs as it produces Word and PowerPoint files but it is faster, does not require rJava and is easier to maintain."*

Comment: `officeR` will unfortunately not write rtf documents. It can do Word, perhaps you can convert to rtf later?

Comment: Please if anyone gone through this or worked on it.. please help me out